# At what point do components sizes get set in RCP Views

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I don't want to be too specific because this could have many applications but if required I can post some code. For simplicity let's say I have an `RCP` view with a `Canvas` on and I want to draw a circle on that `canvas` in the centre. Not with every re-draw, I just want it to start in the centre.

I have tried to do this in the constructor of my extended `canvas` but the `getSize()` method doesn't yet return the correct size. I have tried to `pack()` and `layout()` the parent composite of the View and then get the `canvas` size, still nothing.

So is there somewhere to catch the initial size of the View and components being set?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `SWT.Resize` event. You will get a resize when the control is created.

Comment: I do not get a resize when it's created.

Comment: Even normal resizes don't seem to fire until the view looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean "not with every redraw," but usually, to paint items (and have them continue to be painted, you have to actually "paint" in a control's PaintListener's paintControl() method. This may be what you are looking for:

```
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    @Override
    public void paintControl (PaintEvent event) {
        Rectangle clientRect = canvas.getClientArea();
        event.gc.drawOval(0, 0, clientRect.width - 1, clientRect.height - 1);
    });
```

So you can get the "size" via the control's (canvas's) client-area, and then paint accordingly. You'd need to change the params in the drawOval method to make your circle the appropriate size.

That's how to "paint" and maintain the drawing. Otherwise, it will disappear.